# Can a DIY balloon become a danger?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A couple of years ago I remember reading that a DIY group sent a $25 balloon 20km into the air. This made me think for a while because if they lift about 5Kg that high It would generate more or less 1000kJ of kinetic energy upon impact. Checking the orders of magnitude, in Wikipedia, that’s equivalent of "a 2 tone vehicle at 116 km/h". Which I think is a lot.

There must be some factor that I'm not thinking of (ex: air resistance, hydrogen to kg lifted ratio, etc...) preventing bad intentioned people from dropping that weight whenever they want with a low frequency radio transceiver and wrecking havoc with this apparently simple method, what are those factors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not factoring in air resistance. The falling balloon will hit terminal velocity and stored gravitation potential energy will be converted to heat as it falls (primarily through viscous drag) rather than to kinetic energy.

The energy transferred upon impact will depend largely on the shape and density of the falling object.

A similar, commonly asked question, might give you some more information
http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/could-a-penny-dropped-off/

Comment: If you dropped six Olympic standard 800g javelins from 20km it might be more destructive than dropping 5kg of bubble wrap. It could even be a weapon (hypervelocity rod bundles).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Let's not give people ideas...